# JointState push.back not working

Tags: ros, c++, jointstate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm very newbie in ROS and C++.

I'm trying to read the JointStates values and passed to a vector to work with that values.

```
     sensor_msgs::JointState pos_patas;
    
    std::vector<double> patas_posicion_actual;
    
    void lectura_posicion_patas(const sensor_msgs::JointStatePtr& msg)
    {
      pos_patas = *msg;

      for (int i = 0; i < pos_patas.position.size(); i++)
      {
        ROS_INFO("joint %d position  %.2f", i, pos_patas.position.at(i));
        patas_posicion_actual.push_back(msg->position.at(i));
        ROS_INFO("pata actual %d position %.2f", i, patas_posicion_actual);
      }
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Setup
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //Inicio del nodo en ROS y el node handle
  ros::init(argc, argv, "gait_template");
  ros::NodeHandle node_sub;   //Nodo que se suscribe al JointState

  //Suscripción al tópico del JointStates
  ros::Subscriber sub = node_sub.subscribe("/rhex/joint_states", 1, lectura_posicion_patas);
  ros::Rate rate(10.0);

  pos_patas.position.resize(6);
  patas_posicion_actual.resize(6);

  while(ros::ok()){

    rate.sleep();
    ros::spinOnce();
  }

  return 0;

}
```

And this is the output in the terminal:

```
[ INFO] [1509740062.384800961, 1010.545000000]: joint 0 position  -4.51
[ INFO] [1509740062.384837126, 1010.545000000]: pata actual 0 position 0.00
[ INFO] [1509740062.384851819, 1010.545000000]: joint 1 position  -4.51
[ INFO] [1509740062.384865605, 1010.545000000]: pata actual 1 position 0.00
[ INFO] [1509740062.384878372, 1010.545000000]: joint 2 position  -4.51
[ INFO] [1509740062.384891682, 1010.545000000]: pata actual 2 position 0.00
[ INFO] [1509740062.384904027, 1010.545000000]: joint 3 position  -4.51
[ INFO] [1509740062.384916920, 1010.545000000]: pata actual 3 position 0.00
[ INFO] [1509740062.384929075, 1010.545000000]: joint 4 position  -4.51
[ INFO] [1509740062.384942269, 1010.545000000]: pata actual 4 position 0.00
[ INFO] [1509740062.384954612, 1010.545000000]: joint 5 position  -4.51
[ INFO] [1509740062.384967704, 1010.545000000]: pata actual 5 position 0.00
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274912/jointstate-push.back-not-working/) by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2017-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
also: may I suggest a title change? `JointState` is a ROS msg type, but you're actually using a `std::vector`. And the problem is most likely not with `push_back(..)`, but somewhere else.

**Comment by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) on 2017-11-04**:
I have solve without the push.back function. Just adding to the variable that value

patas_posicion_actual.at(i) = patas_joint_state.position.at(i);

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
I'm not entirely convinced that is really solving it. Passing a `std::vector` without an index to `ROS_INFO(..)` should not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ROS_INFO("pata actual %d position %.2f", i, patas_posicion_actual);
> ```

I'm not sure, but I don't think you can just pass a `std::vector` to `ROS_INFO(..)` and expect it to print anything.

It could well be that the `0.00` you are seeing is actually just garbage memory that happens to evaluate to a `0.00` double.

Try this:

```
ROS_INFO("pata actual %d position %.2f", i, patas_posicion_actual[i]);
```

(note the `[i]` to index into the vector).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:\

> Hello, I'm very newbie in ROS and C++.

In that case I would recommend to *first* get some experience with C++, as your current question is not a ROS one, but a basic C++ one. You'll be much more comfortable with ROS once you know some C++.